# Dynamically create a phone diary usingt javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Can anybody tell me how to implement this piece of code [left side is user input and right hand side is user's output table using javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNbBy.png)

What i have done

```
/*index.html*/
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body onload="createTable()">
    <div class='box'>
        <h4>New Contact</h4>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Phone<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="addRow" value="Add New Row" onclick="addRow()" />
        </p>
        <div id="cont"></div>   <!--the container to add the table.-->
        <p><input type="button" id="bt" value="Submit Data" onclick="submit()" /></p>
    </div>
    

    

    
</body>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="script.js"></script>

</html>

/*style.css*/

body {
    background-color: lightsteelblue;
}
h4{
    text-align: center;
}
.required {
    color: red;
  }

.box {
    width: 300px;
    border: 15px solid white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color:white;
  }
```

What i don't know is how to create that right side table and it will be created only when user is giving all datas on left side and after clicking add its data will added to right side table with an autonumber ID column and on the right side table there was a column Action ,there it need to be create a button that can delete that perticular row
please help me as i have poor knowledge on Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Find the code below to full fille your requirement. Just format html as per your requirement.

```js
var rowId =1;
    function addRow() {
       var tblElement = document.getElementsByClassName('table')[0];
       var row = document.createElement('tr');
       row.id = rowId;
       var name = document.getElementById('formGroupExampleInput').value.trim();
       var phone = document.getElementById('formGroupExampleInput2').value.trim();
       
        var td1 = createElementHtml('', 'td', rowId);
        var td2 = createElementHtml('', 'td', name);
        var td3 = createElementHtml('', 'td', phone);
        var td4 = createElementHtml('', 'td', '');
        
        var btn = createElementHtml('btn' + rowId, 'button', 'Remove');
        btn.value = 'Remove';
        btn.onclick = function() { onClickRemoveRow(this); };
        
         row.appendChild(td1);
         row.appendChild(td2);
         row.appendChild(td3);
         row.appendChild(td4);
         td4.appendChild(btn);
         
         rowId = rowId + 1;
         
         tblElement.appendChild(row);
         
         return false;
    }
    
    function onClickRemoveRow(e) {
        rowId    = e.id.replace('btn','');
         var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
       alert(rowId);
       if (row != null) {
            
        var tblElement = document.getElementsByClassName('table')[0];
            tblElement.removeChild(row);
       }
    }
    
        function createElementHtml(id,tagname, text) {
          var nwtag = document.createElement(tagname);
          nwtag.id = id;
          nwtag.innerText = text;
          if (tagname =='button') {
            nwtag.type = 'button';
          }
          
          return nwtag;
        }
```

```html
  
    
    <div class="row">
      <<div class="col-md-4">
         <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Phone<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
        </div>
        <input type="button" onclick="return addRow()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add"/>
    </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
              <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="ID">#</th>
                      <th scope="col">Name</th>
                      <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                      <th scope="col">Removed</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  </tbody>
                  </table>
    
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: also can u please tell me how to use validation on phone number

Comment: Check link for phone validation.  https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phoit ne-no-validation.php.  Mark as answer if full-fill you requirement.

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php